# How to factorize the polynomial in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring

I need to factor the polynomial $x^5+3x^4+x^3+x^2+3$ into the product of the irreducible ones in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.
The problem is I don't see any whole roots (I tried every possible divisor of 3) in the given polynomial. Does it mean that it is already irreducible?

Comment: Keep in mind that over $\mathbb Z_5$ the possible divisors of $3$ are different than over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think the notation should be made clearer since the question makes perfect sense when $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is the ring of $5$-adic integers. Seeing the answers it seems that here it means $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to check that $-1$ is a root, and by *Horner's algorithm*, you obtain 
$$x^5+3x^4+x^3+x^2+3=(x+1)(x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x-2).$$
Similarly, the quotient has  $2$ as a root and
$$ x^4+2x^3-x^2+2x-2=(x-2)(x^3-x^2+2x+1).$$
The latter quotient has  $-2$ as a root, and
$$x^3-x^2+2x+=(x+2)(x^2+2x+3),$$
so that $$x^5+3x^4+x^3+x^2+3=(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+2x+3). $$
Now the quadratic factor is irreducible because it has no root. Indeed
$$ x^2+2x+3=(x+1)^2+2,$$
and the non-zero squares in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}$/$5\mathbb{Z}$? All the rest is understandable.

Comment: The set of congruence classes of integers modulo $5$. That's  the standard notation, borrowed from group theory. There's also, when one wants to emphasize it's a field, the notation $\mathbf F_5$.

Comment: But isn't 4 a non-zero square in $\mathbb{Z}_5$? Since $4=2\times2$ where $2,4\in\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: Yes, but $4\equiv -1\mod 5$. So I've listed it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand your last statement in the solution. I evaluated $(x+1)^2+2$ for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and got 3, 1, 1, 3, 2 respectively. Neither of the results is divisible by 5, hence the polynomial is irreducible. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. What said is that if this polynomial is not irreducible, it has a root, hence $-2$ is a square in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ – which is impossible since we know the list of squares in that field.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, $2$, $3$, and $4$ are roots of that polynomial in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$. So, your polynomial can be written as$$(x^2+ax+b)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4).$$Since $b\times(-4)=3$, $b=3$. It is not hard now to see that $a=2$.

Comment: So, the value that we get after substituting a number A for x in the polynomial must be divisible by 5. At first, I thought it must equal exactly zero. The only thing that is still unclear to me is why $b\times(-4)=3$

Comment: Because $4=b\times(-2)\times(-3)\times(-4)=b\times(-4)$, since $(-2)\times(-3)=1$.

Comment: In the explanation above you wrote that $b\times(-4)=3$ and here in your comment $b\times(-4)=4$. I am confused. Where does the right part of the equality come from?

Comment: Your polynomial is $x^5+3x^4+x^3+x^2+3$, which turns out to be equal to$$(x^2+ax+b)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4).$$Therefore, their constant terms are equal, which means that $3=b\times(-2)\times(-3)\times(-4)$. Note that, in my previous comment, when I wrote $4=$, what I meant was $3=$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple gcd-based method method that generalizes widely.

Since $\,x^5\!-\!x \equiv \color{#0a0}x(\color{#c00}{x\!-\!1})\cdots (x\!-\!4)\,$ we get all linear factors of $\,f\,$ via $\,\gcd(f,x^5\!-\!x)$

$\color{#0a0}{f(0)\not\equiv 0}\,$ so we can cancel $\color{#0a0}x$ and compute $\,\gcd(f,x^4\!-\!1).\, $ Using the Euclidean algorithm

$\!\bmod x^4\!-\!1\!:\  x^4\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, f \equiv x\!+\!3\!+\!x^3\!+\!x^2\!+\!3\equiv x^3\!+\!x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1\equiv (x^4\!-\!1)/(\color{#c00}{x\!-\!1}) =: g$

so the gcd $\ (f,x^4\!-\!1) = (f\bmod x^4\!-\!1,\,x^4\!-\!1) = (g,\,x^4\!-\!1) = g,\ $ by $\ g\mid x^4\!-\!1$

Therefore every element is a root of $f$ except $\,\color{#0a0}0,\color{#c00}1\,$ so $f = (x\!-\!2)(x\!-\!3)(x\!-\!4)g(x)\,$  where, necessarily, $\,g\,$ is an *irreducible* quadratic, whose coeff's can be computed by comparing terms.

**Remark** $ $ This easily generalizes, e.g. same shape as above for any prime $p\ $ (above is $\,p,a = 5,2)$

$\!\!\begin{align}\bmod p\!:\,\ f(x) &= x^p\! \!-a x^{p-1}\!+\!x^{p-2}\!+\!x^{p-3}\!+\cdots+\! x^2 + a\!+\!1\\[.2em]  
&= (x\!-\!2)(x\!-\!3)\cdots(x\!-\!p\!+\!1)g(x),\ \ \rm by\end{align}$

$\!\bmod x^{p-1}\!-\!1\!:\,\ f \equiv x^{p-2}+\cdots +x + 1 = (x^{p-1}\!-\!1)/(x\!-1\!)\ $ as above

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If it factors nontrivially, one factor will have degree 1 (then it has a root in ${\Bbb Z}_5$) or one factor will have degree 2, by the degree formula. The irreducible polynomials of degree 2 in ${\Bbb Z}_5[x]$ can be enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it more aggressively.

Check that $2$, $3$ and $4$ are roots, which gives the factorization:

$$x^5+3x^4+x^3+x^2+3\equiv x^5-2x^4+x^3+x^2-12=$$
$$=x^5-2x^4+x^3-2x^2+3x^2-6x+6x-12=(x-2)(x^4+x^2+3x+6)\equiv$$
$$\equiv(x-2)(x^4-9x^2-2x+6)=(x-2)(x^2(x-3)(x+3)-2(x-3))=$$
$$=(x-2)(x-3)(x^3+3x^2-2)\equiv(x-2)(x-3)(x^3-2x^2-32)=$$
$$=(x-2)(x-3)(x^3-4x^2+2x^2-32)=(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x^2+2x+8)=$$
$$=(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)((x+1)^2-3).$$
Easy to see that the quadratic factor is irreducible.